# resampling timeseries data per group in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I have timeseries data that I want to query. The data is collected over multiple sensors. I want to direclty resample the data when loading: So each sensor separately resampled. Using pandas this can be reached like this:

```
#df is a pandas dataframe. Index is a timestamp (datetime64).  
df=df.groupby('group').resample('1H').mean()
```

In sql i tried an approach like this:

```
SELECT  date_trunc('hour', timestamp) AS timestamp, avg(signal.value) AS value, source_name, 
FROM signal AS t_signal
GROUP BY(1, t_source.name)
```

This gives me different results, since in the first case with pandas, the resampling will create a row with a unique timestamp even if the original data did not have a datapoint within a specific hour.

The date_trunc does only aggregate existing data. is there a function that does the same as pandas resampling?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a SELECT or table with only the timestamps you want (from-to) and then a full-outer-join with your resampled data should work.

Then, you only have to fill the NULL's with what you want to be the missing data.

Does this help?

Comment: btw, [creating series in sql is not that convenient](https://dzone.com/articles/how-create-range-1-10-sql), but you maybe find a soultion depending on the database system you use. The other way is to create a "template table" from an external source like python.